# GNU Octave 4.0.0 - compiling from souce - error messages - your opinion?

Tags: compiling, make, octave

I have been trying to install Octave 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. During the compiling there were some messages that something is missing on my computer in order to run Octave with all it's normal features.

I would like to get the opinion of some of the experts here and probably how to overcome the current shortcomings.

Paste.ofcode.org is returns an 500 error so that I paste the code here below.

I have saved the terminal output in a normal gedit file, since it is too long to post it here.

[Dowload log file from Dropbox - 68kb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ygyl1f2euv4qq3/Octave_configure_log.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I would install the following libraries for building the graphical interface and using the faster atlas library:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libatlas-base-dev openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk libqrupdate-dev libqhull-dev
```

you also need to set up the java path in your `.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Hi Harris,

I installed all the files and also added the java line in my `/home/USERNAME/.bashrc`. Now `./configure` aborts compiling somewhere around line 362 out of about ~1444 before.

I uploaded the terminal output to Dropbox again. If you like, feel free to have a look.

[link]:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/918076/Octave_Configure_Output02.txt [link]

Comment: Try to install these packages too `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev  libreadline6-dev ibsuitesparse-dev libarpack2-dev`

Comment: Add also these extra packages too `sudo apt-get install bison gperf librsvg2-bin`